# Create a view to display the list of content created by user and any published content

Tags: views

I am creating view for displaying content list and some exposed filters. I wanted to display **all published content of any user** and **all content created by user(current user)**.
Currently i am able to display only own content list by using contextual filter:

- Click "Advanced" > "Contextual Filters"
- "Add" > "Content: Author uid"
- "Provide default value" > "User ID from logged in user"
- Save

How can i display in list **a combination of All published contents from all authors + published and unpublished contents of logged in user**?

Comment: I forgot the name but there is module which defines a permission name "view own unpublish content". You don't need to add contextual filter in any case.

Comment: Yes! i have tried this option but actually this is not satisfying my requirements. When we set Access to "view own unpublish content" that will display only unpublished content.

Comment: No, that should display all the content. Seems you are applying the node status filters as well.

Comment: You need to move the contextual filter down into the filter criteria on the left of the views ui where you can create advanced conditional logic (AND/OR). Do this with [Views arguments in filters](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/itangalo/1086472)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Filter **"User :current"**.if you not get desire result add relation of user table then try it

Answer (score 0):

You anyway want to display all content from all the authors and current user so no need to add contextual filter, then it's going display all the content from your site with logged in user's content too.

Also you can try this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/30752/34082)

Comment: Please avoid previous comment. What i want in list a combination of 
All published content from all authors + published and unpublished content of logged in user