# Image styles deleted on node save

Tags: 8, media

I just created a custom module following this tut:
[generate-programmatically-image-styles-drupal-8](https://www.flocondetoile.fr/blog/generate-programmatically-image-styles-drupal-8)

It works great but the following occurs. When I create a new node and upload the image you see that for every style I have it creates a image (like the custom module should). But when I save the node all the created images are deleted?

Is this a standard function in Drupal that can be disabled? Hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm getting the same issue too. I thought it had something to do with the Crop API, but it happens on nodes without Crops. I'll do some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that image_path_flush() is being fired in Drupal\file_entity\Entity\FileEntity->postSave() even when the image is not actually updated. You can see the issue and proposed resolution outlined here: https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity/issues/2816761