# Allowing a user role to edit only their own content

Tags: 6, users

I am having some difficulty setting up a user role that can access the admin/content/node section of the site but only view their own content.

For the user role i have some permissions set like so (events is a custom content type)

- **create events content**
- **delete own events content**
- **edit own events content**

The admin/content/node will not appear unless i set a permission.

- **administer nodes**

This allows the user role to create, edit, delete any content. Definitely not what i need!

Reference:

- [Permissions Reference](http://drupal.org/node/132202)
- [Possible duplicate](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24674/user-role-cant-view-edit-their-own-unpublished-content)

Can anyone shed some light on how to allow user roles to only access their own content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a view that duplicates this functionality but only references content to the currently logged in user. You could then add in View Bulk Operations to add the edit/delete links usually found on that page.

You could give the view a path of /admin/content/node/self maybe.

Comment: That sounds really awkward for what im trying to achieve, if it is the only option i better give it a go.